# Finding an element with the Java For each loop

Tags: java, for-loop, each

I want to loop through a LinkedList using For each and access the element after the one I am at right now. If I would use an Array and the usual `for(int i = 0; i < ... ; i++)`, I would be looking for the element i+1. Is there a possibility of reaching the element after the one I am at right now?

Comment: ```LinkedList``` implements ```List``` which has a ```get(index)``` method, which you could use.

Comment: What would that do? i++ already does that @YoucefLaidani

Comment: Can you clearly explain : `Is there a possibility of reaching the element after the one I am at right now?`

Comment: You can use the `size()` method and so you can use `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)`

Comment: You could try to use a separate counter and do `list.get(counter + 1)` but in that case you could keep using the normal for loop. There's not much sense in using for-each if you still need the index. Besides that you could track the previous element and when you access the "next" element you execute whatever operation you're doing on the previous one.

Comment: `get(indexOf(actualObj)+1);` which works but is pretty inefficient.

Comment: @Fildor if actualObj is the last?

Comment: @Fildor doing that in a loop could hurt performance tremendously since you'd go from O(n) to O(n^2).

Comment: @Kent I leave it up to OP to handle that. But you are right: it has to be handled.

Comment: @Thomas I stated that it is inefficient. I would prefer using a "traditional" for if I had to access the List by Index. But then again, I would not use a LinkedList ...

Comment: @Lukäs is there a reason for trying to use foreach instead a normal for? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @Fildor okay. but indexOf() takes the first occurrence, and linkedlist can have duplicates. also it checks equality with `equals()` instead of `==`. so your suggestion could give wrong result.

Comment: this is either a theoretical question or a noob question. Just use a while loop on Iterator and do iterator.next(); when you have the element you want.

Comment: I didn't want to use get(index) because its pretty expensive. So I was wondering if there is another way of accessing the object after the one i am at right now. So that i could use 2 objects at the same time.

Comment: @Kent That's correct. But without knowing further details ...

Comment: @Lukäs , you took a LinkedList data-structure, and try to do random access, if I understood you right. But you do care about the performance. I think you are choosing the wrong datastructure...

Comment: Okay well I guess I'll go with an Iterator then. thanks

Comment: Use a (`List`)`Iterator`; just keep the "previous" value in a local variable as you iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility of reaching the element after the one I am at right now?

If you use a simple "for each" loop, then No.  The "current position" within the list is encoded to the list's `Iterator`.  When you use "for each", the `Iterator` is hidden from your application.

Instead you need to do something like this:

```
List<Element> list = ...
Element current = null;
Element next = null;
Iterator<Element> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    current = next;
    next = it.next();
    if (current == null) {
        continue;
    }
    // process 'current' and use `next` when you need to refer to 
    // the following on element.
}
if (next != null) {
    // process 'next' as the last element.
}
```

Notes:

1. If `null` is a valid list element, then use a flag instead.
2. Using two iterators for the same list might give you a neater solution.
3. You could also do something similar to this using a `for each` ... and keeping track of the "previous" element in a variable, like I do above.  See @Jezor's answer.
4. It is inadvisable to use `get(i)` on a (large) `LinkedList` because `get(int)` is an `O(N)` operation for a `LinkedList` in the general case.

Comment: "No" is a bit hard, don't you think? Most possibilities are inefficient but still "possible" ... (ignoring duplicates)

Comment: Won't this iterate over the list two "steps" at a time? For example, every time you return to the top of loop, you would hit elements #0, #2, #4, ... etc. rather than #0, #1, #2... (Not to say this is wrong, just something to consider.)

Comment: @ChrisSprague - Read it again.  There is only one `next()` call for each time round the loop.

Comment: @StephenC ah, you're right. I thought you were alluding to calling `next()` subsequent times in the body, but I see what you're doing now. And, you're accounting for `current` being null in the first pass. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the auto-iterator for-each style loop such as:

```
for (T elem: myList) {
    // ...
}
```

then there isn't an immediate way to access the "next" element while you're looking at the current one without saving a reference to the element you last saw. It is also possible with using [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)), but this approach gets very messy when duplicates are found in the list. Regardless, I think your problem would be better addressed using indexing over the list instead.

If you're iterating over your `LinkedList` object *using indexed-based access* (as opposed to an iterator or for-each, for example,) you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    // ...
    if ((i + 1) < myList.size()) {
        T nextElem = myList.get(i+1); // fetch the element at the next index
        // then do whatever you want with "nextElem"
    }
    // ...
}
```

where `T` refers to the type of `LinkedList` you are using, i.e. `String` if your list definition was something like `LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<>();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can neither determine the index of next element in [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) nor it's value.

You can keep the reference to previous element though:

```
// List is initialized somewhere in the code.
List<Element> elements = ...;

Element previousElement = null;
for (Element element: elements) {
    if (previousElement != null) {
        // ... your code here...
        // previousElement is elements[i]
        // element is elements[i + 1]
    }

    previousElement = element;
}
```

In the above example you can instantiate previousElement with a [null object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/null_object_pattern.htm) to avoid the null check.

What you really want to use is good, old for loop with a counter:

```
List<Element> elements = ...;

for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
    // elements.get(i) is elements[i]
    // elements.get(i + 1) is elements[i + 1]
    // But be careful, (i + 1) will be out of bounds for the last element!
}
```

Don't make your life unnecessarily complicated.